# xorg segfaults after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1 - how to proceed?

Tags: 20.04, xorg, segmentation-fault

I just finished upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1 and after restarting I get a black screen with a blinking cursor (but can't type).

From `Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    10.307] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    10.307] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    10.310] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    10.311] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    10.311]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
[    10.311]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    10.311] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    10.311] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    10.311] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    10.311] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    10.311] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    10.311] (II) Unloading vesa
[    10.311] (EE) 
[    10.311] (EE) Backtrace:
[    10.312] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13c) [0x5580989b311c]
[    10.312] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x60) [0x7fdec4e5841f]
[    10.313] (EE) 2: ? (?+0x0) [0x0]
[    10.313] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[    10.313] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7fdec46fb850]
[    10.313] (EE) 4: ? (?+0x0) [0x55809a1b9f90]
[    10.313] (EE) 
[    10.313] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[    10.313] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    10.313] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

Here is some version information from the beginning of the file:

```
[    10.224] Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-115-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    10.224] Current Operating System: Linux abc-ThinkPad-E485 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64
[    10.224] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[33]=00:00.1 iommu=pt processor.max_cstate=5 vt.handoff=7
[    10.224] Build Date: 04 September 2020  01:34:27PM
[    10.224] xorg-server 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    10.225] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
```

Any ideas how to fix it/get more information?
I wouldn't mind simply downgrading ubuntu but I read that downgrading is not necessarily a good idea either.

I found [this bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/2480), which somehow looks related.
But I don't know how to revert mesa or whether that's really the cause anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apparently I found a solution just after asking here.

Quite some time ago I installed proprietary amdgpu drivers and uninstalling them solved the problem. If other people face the same problem:

```
/usr/bin/amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

I might at some point try to install a newer version of the drivers.

Comment: If nobody posts a better answer, I will accept this in a day or so.

Comment: +1, I often find solutions after giving up and asking! Thanks for posting your answer.

Comment: I'm now experiencing this issue randomly on a brand new machine that's never had the amdgpu pro drivers installed with an Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060, Ubuntu 20.10, and the propriety 450 drivers installed.

Comment: This helped me as well, although I had amdgpu (not pro). I've been looking for several hours. How did you manage to stumble unto this solution?